# Strange random behavior in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table like this:

```
     Id | GroupId | Category
     ------------------------
     1  | 101     | A
     2  | 101     | B
     3  | 101     | C
     4  | 103     | B
     5  | 103     | D
     6  | 103     | A
     ........................
```

I need select one of the `GroupId` randomly. For this I have used the following *PL/SQL* code block:

```
declare v_group_count number;
  v_group_id number;
begin 
  select count(distinct GroupId) into v_group_count from MyTable;
  SELECT GroupId into v_group_id  FROM
  (
    SELECT GroupId, ROWNUM RN FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT GroupId FROM MyTable)
  )
  WHERE RN=Round(dbms_random.value(1, v_group_count));
end;
```

Because I rounded random value then it will be an integer value and the `WHERE RN=Round(dbms_random.value(1, v_group_count))` condition must return one row always. Generally it gives me one row as expected. **But strangely sometimes it gives me no rows and sometimes it returns two rows.** That's why it gives error in this section:

```
SELECT GroupId into v_group_id
```

**Anyone knows the reason of that behaviour?**

Comment: There is an additional issue with your solution. You might want to check my edited answer.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, I have checked your edit. Good approach!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`round(dbms_random.value(1, v_group_count))` is being executed for every row, so every row might be selected or not.

---

P.s.

#### ROUND is a bad choice.

The probability of getting any of the edge values (e.g. 1 and 10) is half the probability of getting any other value (e.g. 2 to 9).
It is 0.0555... (1/18) Vs. 0.111... (1/9)

```
[  1,1.5) --> 1
[1.5,2.5) --> 2
.
.
.
[8.5,9.5) --> 9
[9.5, 10) --> 10
```

---

```
select          n,count(*)
from           (select          round(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) as n
                from            dual
                connect by      level <= 100000
                )
group by        n
order by        n
;
```

---

```
    N   COUNT(*)
    1   5488
    2   11239
    3   11236
    4   10981
    5   11205
    6   11114
    7   11211
    8   11048
    9   10959
    10  5519
```

#### My recommendation is to use FLOOR on dbms_random.value(1,N+1)

```
    select          n,count(*)
    from           (select          floor(dbms_random.value(1, 11)) as n
                    from            dual
                    connect by      level <= 100000
                    )
    group by        n
    order by        n   
    ;
```

---

```
N   COUNT(*)
1   10091
2   10020
3   10020
4   10021
5   9908
6   10036
7   10054
8   9997
9   9846
10  10007
```

Comment: @FaridImranov To prove this out you could move it to a cross join so that it's generated 1 time for all records; if the problem goes away... you likely have your answer

Comment: It looks like logical approach, can you show the source of this approach?

Comment: @xQbert, can you explain me how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps like this: `select count(distinct GroupId) into v_group_count from MyTable;
  SELECT GroupId into v_group_id  FROM
  (
    SELECT GroupId, ROWNUM RN, RND FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT GroupId FROM MyTable
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT Round(dbms_random.value(1, v_group_count)) RND FROM DUAL) B
  )
  WHERE RN=RND;`  since we have an inline view (B) which generates 1 and only 1 value that same value will exist on all records.

Comment: For performance issue the answer of @Gordon Linoff is the best. But I want to understand why it gives unexpected rows count. And Dudu Markovitz's answer looks like correct

Answer (score 8):

If you want to select one randomly:

```
declare v_group_count number;
  v_group_id number;
begin 
  SELECT GroupId into v_group_id
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GroupId
        FROM MyTable
        ORDER BY dbms_random.value
       ) t
  WHERE rownum = 1
end;
```

Comment: Thaks for your answer. But the reason of strange behvior is interesting for me

Comment: In MSSQL an order by item must be present in select list when `distinct` is specified. Is this not a case in Oracle?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, no, it does not need it in `oracle`.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I'd be very surprised if MSSQL couldn't order by a column that wasn't in its select list. I don't have access to an MSSQL db, but I'm pretty sure it ought to handle a query of the form `select col1 from some_table order by col2`. Are you saying that it can't?

Comment: It can't if there is `distinct` involved, because there is an ambiguity then. Oracle seems to allow expressions that do not depend on columns, but as soon as `order by` refers to a column I also get `ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression`.

Comment: On the other hand MSSQL would complain with `select distinct GroupID from MyTable order by rand(1)`.